# У той и другой было по двухмесячному щенку, которые грызли все подряд.

Tags: синтаксис, морфология, согласование

Можно ли так согласовывать: *щенок* в ед.ч., а союзное слово *которые* во мн.ч.?

Answer (score 2):

**У той и другой было по двухмесячному щенку, которые грызли все подряд.**

Это единственный вариант, согласование делается по смыслу, а не по форме.